# In Scala.js, how do I toggle visibility of elements in a class?

Tags: javascript, scala.js

In a Scala.js program, I want to toggle the visibility of all elements on the HTML page in the class "my-img". What I have so far is

```
import org.scalajs.dom
import dom.document

val elems: dom.NodeList = document.getElemsByClassName("my-img")
for (i <- 0 until elems.length) {
   val e: dom.Node = elems(i)
   e.style.display = "none"  <-- this chokes, says style is not a member of Node
```

At this point I am trying to access the style member of a Node, which according to the Javascript docs should be there, but Scala.js is giving me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Note that this is more a Javascript question than a Scala.js one per se.)

There are a few answers, depending whether you're willing to include the jQuery library. This is a somewhat heavy but extremely common library in the Javascript world, which is also often used in Scala.js programming. It isn't required, but it makes this sort of thing considerably easier.

There are two popular Scala.js "facades" (Scala descriptions) for this library; I wrote one of them, [jquery-facade](https://github.com/jducoeur/jquery-facade). If you pull that in (as described on that page), the problem becomes fairly trivial:

```
import org.querki.jquery._

// Fetch all of the nodes. jQuery uses CSS selectors, more or less,
// so this means "everything with class my-img".
val myImgs = $(".my-img")
// Hide all of them. myImgs is a JQuery object -- a wrapper around
// all of those nodes -- so a single call hides all of them:
myImgs.hide()
// Or show them:
myImgs.show()
```

That's untested (and I'm battling flu today, so please forgive me any errors), but I think it should work...

Comment: I updated my response. I'd like to understand more basic Javascript issues within Scala.js before I try to use jQuery.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Wow, that's -- well, not how I've ever seen anybody try to do this, precisely because it's such a pain to work that way.  But to get to some of the confusion: one big problem with that NodeList is that it is a raw list of XML Nodes, *not* HTML nodes.  XML nodes don't know anything about "style".  So you have to manually do a `.asInstanceOf[HTMLElement]` to tell JavaScript that you have magic external knowledge that it doesn't know about.

Comment: This is a consequence of the fact that we have a strongly typed language (Scala) in a weakly typed environment (JS/DOM).  JavaScript traditionally plays fast and loose with this stuff, and quietly ignores the fact that you are sometimes doing stuff that is nonsensical from a type perspective.  Scala doesn't let you do that -- if you have out-of-band knowledge that an object of type A is actually type B, you have to say so explicitly.

Comment: The result is that `.asInstanceOf[]` is rather more common in Scala.js than in ScalaJVM -- it is how you tell the compiler that you know that this is really a different type (typically a more precise type) than the API claims.

Comment: So anyway: you'll find the definition of `style` [here, on HTMLElement](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js-dom/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/scalajs/dom/raw/Html.scala#L4106).  So each of those `dom.Node`s needs to be cast to that, to use this.

Comment: Thanks very much. As you can guess I'm a Javascript and Scala neophyte, both. Your answer will help me look in the right place for solutions not only for this problem, but I think I'll have more of a clue in the future.

Comment: Happy to help.  If you're not already there, you might want to join the [Gitter group scala-js/scala-js](https://gitter.im/scala-js/scala-js) -- much of the Scala.js community is there, and it's a quicker-turnaround place to ask questions, especially when you're starting out.